# using mod_rewrite on ajax site to load root index page when you access folders in url

Tags: ajax, mod-rewrite, history.js

I'm building an Ajax site that runs off of a root-level index.html file and uses history.js for pushState/popState, which I have updating the urls such that they are nice and clean without hashes or bangs (Example: site.com/section/1).

How can I do a mod_rewrite so that when a user tries to link to site.com/section/1 or site.com/section (or anywhere other than the root), the server serves up site.com/index.html?

From there the js would load the requested content in the url via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html   [L]
```

If you want to do something with the actual request (the /section/1 part) you can access it via **$1**. Example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html?path=$1   [L]
```

Which will rewrite /section/1 to /index.html?path=/section/1